# Not-greater-than in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a query that I want to filter out all the results if a column is 1 or greater (if it's 0, NULL, or empty, I want to keep it in the results).

So I thought I'd use !< per [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_comparison_operators.htm), but when I try

```
WHERE column_name !< 0
```

I get the error

```
'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 unrecognized token: "!<"'
```

Is the tutorial page wrong?  How else would I do this query?

Answer (score 1):

Try this `where` clause

```
WHERE column_name < 1 
   or column_name is NULL 
   or column_name = ''
```

Comment: I guess this works... but is there really no "!<" operator like the tutorial page said?